Hair compression techniques
I recently purchased hair with a very high resolution, and I need to use it in Clo3D. Unfortunately, the software struggles with such heavy assets. As a fashion designer, working in Clo3D is essential because I rely on fast, straightforward rendering while maintaining a realistic avatar, which is crucial for my projects.
The problem I’m facing is that the hair I bought is made of dense geometry, resulting in an extremely large file. Additionally, it doesn't integrate well with Clo3D, showing glitches—especially at the hair tips:

I've noticed that simpler hair models that use texture maps work better with Clo3D:

Since the software handles lighter geometry more efficiently while still achieving realistic results, I’m wondering if it’s possible to simplify the hair's geometry and bake it into texture maps to use in Clo3D?
If anyone has experience with this process or can recommend useful tutorials, I would greatly appreciate the guidance. I haven’t been able to find the specific information I need.
Thank you in advance!
Ps; I tryied using decimate modifier but my pc crushes.

Try putting the hair mesh into EDIT mode and then menu::mesh::cleanup::decimate and choose a lower value than the 1.0 offered, which is 100% (no reduction).  So 0.3 would be 1.0 - 0.3 or 70% reduction in mesh.   I often find that hair can be greatly decimated with no visible problems.

Compared to using cards for hairs it will still be magnitudes higher polycount. If the hairs were made out of curves, i would try something like this. But if they are full meshes, I can't think of an easy way to quickly turn them into cards.
